# "git gc" says fatal: failed to write ref-pack file

Tags: git

When I run `git gc` on a repository I have, it says

```
fatal: failed to write ref-pack file
error: failed to run pack-refs
```

What does this error mean and how do I solve it?

Comment: Is the `.git` directory writable by your user? Is there enough space left on your storage device?

Comment: @knittl: I think it was the storage space. I was using it to try to free some room because I was low on it. I've cleared some other files and now it works. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.git` directory must be writable by your user and you must have enough free space on your storage device.

When Git creates a new pack, it first creates the new pack and after verifying its correctness it will delete the old pack as well as the newly packed loose objects. IOW you have to have at least the current size of your object database available as free space (simplified).

Comment: Did not solve this error for me. I have 20G of space and can do `touch .git/test`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning is all of your git directory writable? Including the refs, objects, and all other folders and files?

Comment: Dropbox sync locked my files :-)